# Convert maplibrejs url coordinates to mbtiles tile_coumn and tile_row

Tags: vector-tiles, mbtiles, maplibre-gl

I am using maplibrejs as my front end framework it makes request like this :
`http://localhost:8080/gis/14/9240/2582` to my backend code to get tiles.

As my backend I have used **tileserver-gl, which works perfectly fine with this setup**.

To understand how everything works, I created my own backend to serve vector tiles.

My Backend (in nodejs) gets its data by SQL querying an `data.mbtiles` file: `SELECT * FROM tiles WHERE zoom_level = ${z} AND tile_column = ${x} AND tile_row = ${y}`

However when I open this `data.mbtiles` files in sqllite viewer, I see no tiles with this configs: z=14, x=9240, and y=2582
I see something like this:

[image]

I wanted to know how to convert a request like this `http://localhost:8080/gis/14/9240/2582` to fetch the appropriate tile using SQL. Tileserver-gl is able to do this with same `data.mbtiles` file.

Comment: I'm a little confused. If your SQLite table doesn't have a tile for 14/9240/2582, there is no data for that tile. If you're not sure, use a `SELECT` statement to see if such data exists? There are hundreds of millions of level 14 tiles-- you usually render a subset unless you're working with big data

Comment: @BarryCarter I figured it out. The Mbtiles stores tile in [TMS](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TMS) way. After going though source code of tileserver-gl, I came to know that y cordinate needs to be converted this way: `y = (1 << z) - 1 - y;`

Answer (score 1):

OK so found out the answer on my own.
After going though the source code of tileserver-gl came to know that before doing the sql query, the y coordinates needs to be transformed:

```
// Flip Y coordinate because MBTiles files are TMS.
y = (1 << z) - 1 - y;

//now do the SQL query: moever make sure that you set headers before sending response: noe js code
res.setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-protobuf");
res.setHeader("Content-Encoding","gzip");
```